# Join tables and generate complete percentage

Tags: php, sql, ajax

2I have two tables; 'goal' & 'activity' which share goal_id. A goal has many activities, activity is for one goal. The activity table has a status which only has 3 possible integer entries; 0 (not started), 1(In-progress), 2(complete).

I am wanting to be able to query the database, and create a percentage complete status figure.

For instance, if 1 Goal has 4 Activities with status values of; 0, 0, 0, 2. That would represent that Goal is 25% complete. In-Progress represents 50% complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out in the end...

```
<?php

require '../global/head.php'; 

function goalPercentage($goalid){
global $mysqli;

$activities = array();
$percentage = 0;

if ($result = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM user_goal where goal_id='".$goalid."'")) {
    if($result -> num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result -> fetch_object()) {
            global $mysqli;
            $goal_id = $row->goal_id;
            if ($results = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM user_activity where goal_id='".$goalid."'")){

                if($results -> num_rows > 0) {
                    while ($row = $results -> fetch_object()) {
                        array_push($activities, $row->goal_id);

                        if($row->status == 0)
                        {
                            $percentage += 0;
                        }

                        else if($row->status == 1)
                        {
                            $percentage += 50;
                        }

                        else if ($row->status == 2)
                        {
                            $percentage += 100;
                        }

                    }
        }}

        else {
            return 0;
        }

        }
    } 


    else {
        echo "No Results to display :(";
    }}


//echo count($activities);
//echo $percentage;

$percentageResult = $percentage / count($activities);
//echo $result;
return round($percentageResult);
}
?>
```